# Relation between entities in 2 separate server with Typeorm

Tags: database, typeorm, relation

I have a question concerning relations in typeorm.

Let's say that I have a product entity in database A linked to a VAT entity in database B.
The two databases are in separate  servers.

The purpose is to fetch the data from a graphql endpoint.

I first tried to define a vatId in product and a relation to a Vat class. My goal was to fetch Vat from db B in the resolver using another connection and link it to product.

The problem is that the two Vat types do not correspond and I have a type problem in Typescript.

We can not link 2 entities from different connection I think because when trying to generate the migration, TypeOrm do not find the another Entity.

It is possible to link an entity to another database but not to another connection.

I think the best to do is to define an Vat interface and link it in the product but I have no idea on how to do that.

Do you have any suggestions?

Your help will be greetly appreciable.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, TypeORM allows to establish different DB connections, but it's not possible to link entities, because it won't understand, from which connection to get them (for now it's only @Entity({ database: "DBNAME" }) supported).

The best way would be establishing interface and pass vat through constructor of entity.

For example:

```
@Entity()
export class Product {

vat?: VatInterface

constructor(vat: VatInterface) {
  this.vat = vat
 }
}
```

Separately:

```
@Entity()
export class Vat implements VatInterface {
// specify all entity fields here and in interface for Product entity to use
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

I have implemented the solution and It appears that it is not necessary to inherit an interface.

You can just use a vatId property and use the @AfterLoad event to load the vat when you fetch the Product.